# projection and perpendicular dot product type

Tags: linear-algebra

Vector y, vector x, plane P. I will write $proj_p(x)$ and just $proj x$

> What is $-2y\cdot projx - 2y \cdot perp x$

So it is

$-2y(projx + perpx ) = -2y\cdot(x) = -2 (y \cdot x)$ ? Is this right?

Comment: you should explain more what the question asks cause it is very confusing

Comment: If $projx+perpx=x$ then what you wrote seems correct. And according to a certain likely guess what $projx$ and $propx$ mean, the equation is true. But that's still just a guess unless you can define your symbols. (It's best to _edit_ the question in order to show definitions.)